# PHP capture GPS position elements with regex

Tags: php, gps

Hi I have some input like so:

```
$string = "0°25'30"S, 91°7'W"
```

I want formulate a regex expression in php which captures the individual elements so that I end up with:

```
$position_array = array([0] => 0 [1] => 25 [2] => 30 [3] => S [4] => 91 [0] => 7 [0] => W)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you setting yourself up for failure with this method? In the example provided, you have 0 degrees, 15 minutes, 30 seconds south, and 91 degrees, 7 minutes west. It's an unequal amount of elements in your array, without any meaningful association of the values. If you look at your array, what does index '4' represent? 91 what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off of the top of my head, I would try this:

```
$array = array_filter(preg_split("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/",$string), function ($segment) {
    return strlen(trim($segment));
});
```

Comment: One question. How can I make sure that I get 0 in an element rather than no element in the array?

Comment: Got it - remove the `array_filter()`

Comment: If you just remove array_filter() you'll end up with whitespace in your results. I updated the function to include a callback that will only remove whitespace.

Comment: Also, please be so kind as to accept this answer if it's the correct one.